# x/y axis graph tool [text file input]

Tags: python, graph

Is there a free tool I can download that will display a graph given a set of x,y coordinates in a text file?  Or is there a python module I could use that would give me a quick and dirty view of a graph?  Excel is not an option because I do not have it.  I would prefer something light weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

If you want a python solution, use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/). It is a bit heavy weight, but once setup, it is very simple to use.

Comment: thanks, yea im am downloading matplotlib now.  It seems easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something **very** quick and dirty, you could try ascii-plotter:

http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/ascii-plotter/

Otherwise I would go with matplotlib

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/

matplotlib in combination with numpy is very powerful:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x,y = np.loadtxt('xycoords.txt')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

if 'xycoords.txt' is a simple flat file with two columns of numbers representing your x and y data. And of course there are more options for varying levels of data and plotting complexity.